# Can I have a c# dictionary<type,type> use those types in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, function, generics, lambda

I want to do something like

```
public class someClass{

    public void somemethod<T>(){ 
        //dosomething with T;
    }

     public void someothermethod<U>(){ 
        //dosomething with U;
    }
}
```

meanwhile in another class

```
IDictionary<Type,Type> dic = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
dic.add(ClassA, InterfaceA);
dic.add(ClassB, InterfaceB);
dic.add(ClassC, InterfaceC);
dic.add(ClassD, InterfaceD);

dic.foreach(kvp => somemethod<kvp.key>().someothermethod<kvp.value>());
```

this doesn't seem to work. Inside the angle brackets, Visual Studio is telling me it can't resolve kvp? What am I doing wrong? Any help or examples is always appreciated.

Comment: `somemethod` and `someothermethod` are generic methods?

Comment: yes somemethod and someothermethod are both generics

Comment: Can you post some sample signatures?

Comment: Done nemesv - see edited post

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really about dictionaries at all - it's about calling generic methods when you only know the type at execution time.

You can do it with reflection, using `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`, then invoking the result:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        InvokeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        InvokeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
    }

    static void InvokeGenericMethod(Type type)
    {
        var method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("GenericMethod");
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        generic.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public static void GenericMethod<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("typeof(T) = {0}", typeof(T));
    }    
}
```